# Flutter layout and virtual keyboard

Tags: android, ios, flutter

first, sorry for my bad english ^^
With an Flutter Application i have a Scaffold which contains a Container->BoxDecoration->DecorationImage.

but when the virtual keyboard appears on a field, he flattened the background image. Whith : resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false on Scaffold, no problem, except that the keyboard no longer goes up the field view.

Any solution to keep the background correctly ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Perhaps wrap the container with a SingleChildScrollView or ListView. You can also set physics to none so that it can't actually scroll.

Comment: for informations : the field are injected in child of container in column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, // HERE
      body: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: imgLoginScreen.image,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[LoginScreenContent()],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: why this virtual keyboard is never isolated on a different layer, on ios same worries, and from the beginning of the mobile development ^^